# Json array in post method Apex RestFul

Tags: post, plsql, oracle-apex

I successfully create a post service that accepts data in the request body of the xml structure, but now there is a need to get an array of type json from the request body and process it, but I cannot find an example or documentation for this solution .

Answer (score 0):

Using a REST API defined like the example below, you can process both JSON and XML using the same endpoint.  Using the **Content-Type** header, the user/application sending the information to the API can specify if they are sending JSON or XML.

I tested the code below using ORDS 19.2 and Oracle 19c.

```
BEGIN
    ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA (p_enabled               => TRUE,
                        p_url_mapping_type      => 'BASE_PATH',
                        p_url_mapping_pattern   => 'api-test',
                        p_auto_rest_auth        => FALSE);

    ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE (p_module_name => 'v1', p_base_path => '/v1/');

    ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE (p_module_name => 'v1', p_pattern => 'demo');

    ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER (p_module_name   => 'v1',
                         p_pattern       => 'demo',
                         p_method        => 'POST',
                         p_source_type   => ords.source_type_plsql,
                         p_source        => '
DECLARE
    l_input        clob := :body_text;
    l_input_json   json_array_t;
    l_input_xml    XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    OWA_UTIL.mime_header (''text/plain'');

    IF OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env (''content-type'') = ''application/json''
    THEN
        l_input_json := json_array_t.parse (l_input);
        htp.p (l_input_json.stringify);
    ELSIF OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env (''content-type'') = ''application/xml''
    THEN
        null;
        l_input_xml := xmltype (l_input);
        htp.p (l_input_xml.getstringval);
    ELSE
        HTP.p (''Unsupported content type'');
        :status_code := 500;
    END IF;
END;');

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Below are some screenshots from Postman showing how to send the different content types

[Example sending XML content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdRFx.png)

[Example sending JSON content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYock.png)

[Example sending unknown content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flGsP.png)